# PHP mysql table create doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

PHP mysql table create doesn't work!
Why does this code not work?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('allheight', $con);

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE Posts
(
PostID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title varchar(15),
Picture varchar(2000),
Description text,
Height text
)'; 


mysql_query($sql, $con);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The problem here is that the code can't seem to create the table "Posts".

Comment: What error message does MySQL return?

Comment: you shouldn't use the `mysql_` functions anymore. Also, check out the manual on how to get the error-message from a mysql-query. and do some basic debugging, what happens when, and give us that info.

Comment: Try that SQL statement inside a MySQL console, or in phpMyAdmin - and let us know what error you get. Contrary to your statement, MySQL's `CREATE TABLE` works very well indeed, and has done for years.

Comment: To answer your question - the code doesn't work because you coded it badly. Had you checked the errors you get, you'd know what you did wrong.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys now I figured it out. and now I know that just by looking at it youll know why it doesn't work. Its missing the declaration of PostID as the tables primary key. thanks to Sirko

Answer (score 3):

If you had looked up the MySQL error message, it would have been obvious:

> 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

So change your SQL to

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
PostID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title varchar(15),
Picture varchar(2000),
Description text,
Height text,
PRIMARY KEY(PostId)
)
```

Comment: Or just do it in one string: `PostId serial primary key`.

Comment: oops my bad. thanks to you dude, It didn't work because I wasn't able to declare postID as the primary key(which is what I want to do). Nice observation thanks. Sorry for me being so noob.

Answer (score 1):

This sql query produces the following error:

**Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.**

Add this to the end of your query:

```
CREATE TABLE Posts
(
PostID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title varchar(15),
Picture varchar(2000),
Description text,
Height text,
KEY (PostID)
)
```